# Windows 10 laptop keeps going to sleep after a few minutes of idle despite power options

Tags: remote-desktop, sleep

I have a laptop running Windows 10 and setup for RDP. I use the old app Terminals to RDP into the machine and the connection is fine while I am active.

However, it keeps going to sleep after a few minutes (not sure how many exactly, but less than ten) of inactivity, despite setting the power options to sleep after 30 minutes and hibernate after 1 hour. I'm struggling to figure out why it keeps going to sleep, despite the settings in the power options.

How can I troubleshoot this mystery?

**Update:**
After seeing some replies and comments, I went through and updated the BIOS and ran the commands listed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856010 to see if I could at least disable all sleep and hibernate.  That seemed to work, in that the laptop did not seem to sleep or hibernate at all, with or without connecting via RDP.

I then tried to reenable sleep on AC power for 1 hour, and the problem returned.  I was even able to observe that it would go to sleep without ever connecting to an RDP session.  My test was to ping, confirm no replies, then send a WOL, and then ping continuously.  I started seeing the replies and then after a minute or two (once it woke up) and then I could see the replies stop after 1-2mins.

I can always wake the machine fine, but it seems to go to sleep mode after ~1-2 minutes of inactivity, despite setting the power options to sleep after 1 hour (i even tried 2 hours, same thing).  Hopefully some part of this helps someone solve this riddle.

Answer (score 1):

Remote Desktop usually has an idle timeout setting. This led me to check if Terminals has the same option. This issue appears to indicate someone else has the same problem https://github.com/Terminals-Origin/Terminals/issues/225 and it is not currently an option that can be adjusted .

I'm not sure if terminals uses some native windows components. You could always try setting this group policy to see if it extends the idle timeout duration. I haven't reviewed the terminal source code myself.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-server-for-it-pro/idle-time-out-gpo-for-remote-desktop-services-sessions-not/m-p/3413579

This may be where it is set in the source code. You could try modifying it to a custom value and compiling from source code.

https://github.com/Terminals-Origin/Terminals/blob/master/Source/Terminals.Plugins.Rdp/RdpTimeOutOptions.cs

After seeing your new update, perhaps you can run the powercfg /sleepstudy and or /systemsleepdiagnostics to gather more information? Documentation LInk https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/powercfg-command-line-options#option_systemsleepdiagnostics

Comment: Unfortunately, this happens whem connecting using RDP an and even without ever connecting to RDP.  I've updated the question accordingly.